# State Pattern in C++ with undefined variables

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-pattern, predefined-variables

Hello I tried to implement State pattern in C++ based on code from [sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/java/3) site that has been written for Java.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
class State {
public:
    virtual void pull(class Fan* f) = 0;
};

class Off;
class Medium;
class High;

class Fan {
private:
    State* current_state;
public:
    void set_state(State* s) {
        current_state = s;
    }
    Fan() {
        current_state = new Off();
    }
    void pull() {
        current_state->pull(this);
    }

};

class Off:public State{
public:
    void pull(Fan *f){
        f->set_state(new Medium());
        cout << "Medium speed" << endl;
    }
};
class Medium:public State {
public:
    void pull(Fan* f) {
        f->set_state(new High());
        cout << "Max speed" << endl;
    }
};
class High :public State {
public:
    void pull(Fan *f) {
        f->set_state(new Off());
        cout << "The fan is off" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Fan* fan = new Fan();
    int c;
    while (1)
    {
        cin>>c;
        fan->pull();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you see before the "Fan" class I have predefined state classes. But compiler gives me an errors  *use undefined types*

The second question is that on *sourcemaking* site there is C++ implementation of the state pattern, but it also gives me an error and the code in the main function is unclear. The link is [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1). Thank you

Comment: Can you post the compiler error regarding what types are undefined?

Comment: Error C2027 use of undefined type 'Off' Project111

Comment: Error C2027 use of undefined type 'Medium' Project111

Comment: Error C2027 use of undefined type 'High' Project111

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload the screenshot - there is no such option

Comment: Does the question linked by Neil help?

Comment: No it doesn't because as I mentioned -  I predefined the classes, but compiler is still gives me an Error.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler needs to see complete type when you create an object like `current_state = new Off();`. You can sort that out by separating method declaration and definition [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f02edd9b914a5e6f). As you can see I even removed the forward declarations because they are not necessary. @Neil Please remove the mark as duplicate because it really doesn't help OP.

Comment: I even tried to check predefine classes with parent signature. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you also please see the code on the second link - this is pure C++ implementation of the state pattern, but the code in the main function is very strange. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1 Thank you

Comment: This one gave a warning because of missing virtual destructor for `State` class and a few syntax errors in `main()`. See my [fixed code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d569b090449bf6e). The last one is hard to spot: `(fsm.*ptrs[num])();` ... here no space is allowed between `.` and `*` because `.*` is a single operator.